# Auto driver installation on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, drivers

Is there any way to completely automate driver installation in Windows 7?

I need to:
1. Completely uninstall previous driver including its software
2. Restart computer
3. Install new drivers from specified folder
4. Restart computer again

Maybe there are some programs that can do this. Or it can be done somehow by DevCon (points 1 and 3).

Answer (score -3):

You can do this by:-

**1. Turning Windows Update "On"** and select auto update option

(this will update your whole windows systems as well as essential Drivers indeed)

and

2. **Go to Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Right Click on PC-Icon > Device Installation Setting**> **Download Automatically**

(by doing this Devices Drivers are auto-updated by Internet)

Comment: This doesn't even address the question.

Comment: Using Microsoft drivers for some OEM hardware will cerate issues as OEMs use proprietary drivers for some chipsets.  Video is a common example